# Haskell Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Char’ list comprehension

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension

So I'm trying to go through a list of films and output the title of each film, the compiler is saying that is couldn't match type `[Char]` with `Char`.
The thing is I want `[Char]` (A string) and not `Char`?? I'm confused as to why it wants a character and not a string?

```
fas:: [Film] -> String
fas database = [title x | x <- database]

test.hs:55:27: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Char’
      Expected type: Char
        Actual type: String
    • In the expression: title x
      In the expression: [title x | x <- database]
      In an equation for ‘fas’:

          fas database = [title x | x <- database]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've probably worded this poorly which hasn't helped me when trying to search other people have the same problem :/

regards, a novice

Comment: `fas database = map title database` or just `fas = map title` would be preferable to a list comprehension here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you want to do correctly, the signature should be:

```
fas:: [Film] -> [String]
```

Indeed, a **list of strings**.

Why? Because you map **every** film to its title. Now since a **title is a `String`**, the result is a list of `String`s.

The **compiler is actually complaining in the other way than you interpret it**: since `type String = [Char]`, you wrote implicitly:

```
fas :: [Film] -> [Char] -- incorrect
```

whereas it should be:

```
fas :: [Film] -> [[Char]]
```

Comment: "Why? Because you map every film to its title." - This made perfect sense, thank you SO MUCH!